# How to get a list of all of a database's secondary indixes in RethinkDB

Tags: python, rethinkdb

In Python, how can I get a list of all a database's secondary indixes?

For example, in the web UI under "Tables" you can see the list of "Secondary indexes" (in this case only `timestamp`); I would like to get this in the Python environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/python/) doc about secondary indexes in RethinkDB.

You can get list of all indexes on table (e.x. "users") using this query:

```
r.table("users").index_list()
```

If you want to get all secondary indexes for all tables, you can query table list and after that get indexes for each. I don't know python, but in Java Script you can do it using this query:

```
r.tableList().map(function(table){
  return {table: table,
    indexes: r.table(table).indexList()};
})
```

I think, in python it looks like this:

```
r.table_list().map(lambda name:{table: name,indexes: r.table(name).index_list()})
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. For reference, the documentation for `index_list()` is at [https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/index_list/](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/index_list/).